# JQuery Mobile: how to go back to previously previously used form?

Tags: jquery-mobile

***here is the setup:***
**/sampleForm/index.html** has **#Form1Form** section
**/entity/index.html** has **#SearchForm** section
**/search/index.html** has **#SearchResults** section

***here is the intention:***
user wants to populate a field (based on a search) on sampleForm/index.html.
so user clicks a button and entity/index.html is loaded by AJAX.
user enters search criteria and clicks a button.
a little Ajax-PHP happens and the result is saved to sessionStorage.
then search/index.html is loaded by Ajax, and the results are rendered.
each line of results gets an "Insert Back" button.

***here is the problem:***
when user clicks "Insert Back", the intent is to return to **#Form1Form**.
but nothing happens.

at this point, and to troubleshoot, i tried to manually run '$.mobile.changePage("#Form1Form")' on the console and got an unidentified

while a manual run of '$.mobile.changePage("../sampleForm/")' would be successful, but it loses previous inputs.

<strike>(note 1: I wish to return to **#Form1Form** so that I preserve any input before he started searching...)</strike>

(note 2: I am writing search/index.html that way because I was hoping to re-use it for any other similar task..)

Any suggestions as to what's wrong?
Is there a better way of doing what I am trying to achieve?
Is it possible to reload a section that is already in the DOM?

---

edit: i have tried to run $.mobile.back(); on console and even used the data-rel back buttons but the user input still goes away so I guess I have to implement something else for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get me wrong but you need to spend some time read official documentation so you can find how jQuery Mobile page handling works. But have no fear I will explain everything to you.

When working with jQuery Mobile you can use two kind of page templates. First one uses one **HTML** file with multiple pages inside, second one has multiple **HTML** files where every **HTML** files one page inside. When I say page I mean **data-role="page"**.

Only first file is fully loaded into the **DOM** and it will always stay there unless you refresh the page (which is impossible if you are working with Phonegap). Subsequent **HTML** pages will only stay in the **DOM** while they are active, as soon as you open another **HTML** file, jQuery Mobile will remove previous page (**HTML** file) from the **DOM**. This is done to prevent large memory footprint in the **DOM**.

You can solve this is two ways:

1. Put all necessary pages inside first initial HTML file, they will always persist inside the DOM. Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/secrets-of-a-good-jquery-mobile-page-architecture/)**.
2. Turn on page cashing, cash wanted pages and prevent them from been removed.

Comment: Hello again. Thank you so much for taking time to answer. I think understand that part of JQuery Mobile behavior. I was a bit puzzled though because #Form1Form (JQM Page) is part of the initial HTML page, and is visible in the DOM (based on Chrome's Inspect Element tab). Hence, I thought it would have been possible to do a `$.mobile.changePage("#Form1Form");`